# On continuous surjective function that takes every value at most a finite no. of times

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous surjective function which takes every value at most a finite number of times , then is it true that $f$ is strictly monotone ?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Consider for instance $f:x\mapsto x(x-1)(x+1)$.

Comment: Why do you think it would be?

Comment: Why did this get a downvote?

Comment: @M.Vinay The question is missing rather a lot of context or details - there's no motivation for the question, nor any explanation of why the author thinks that this might be the case.  As such, I downvoted, as missing research effort - if the author were to explain what they're having trouble with, I'd be happy to upvote it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849120/another-question-on-continuous-surjective-functions

Comment: @T.Bongers Makes sense. Then I advise Souvik Dey to add the context given in the linked question to this question as well.

Answer (score 5):

Try $x+2$sin$x$.  It is continuous and clearly takes arbitrarily small and arbitrarily large values.  So the Intermediate Value Theorem implies it is surjective.  And its derivative is $1+2$cos$x$, which you can easily graph and and see that it takes positive and negative values.  In fact you can see that our original function is monotonic on no interval of the form $(-\infty,a)$ or $(a,\infty$).

[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest a cubic function, but I like this example better.

Answer (score 4):

No. Let $f(x)$ be a cubic polynomial with three real roots (with at least two distinct). For example $f(x) = (x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)$.

[image: Graph]