# Another question on continuous surjective functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

It is known thta if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous surjective function that takes every value at most twice then $f$ is strictly monotone . My question is " What is the maximum value of $n$ such that if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous surjective function that takes every value at most $n$ times then $f$ is strictly monotone " ?

The answers to the question
[On continuous surjective function that takes every value at most a finite no. of times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849104/on-continuous-surjective-function-that-takes-every-value-at-most-a-finite-no-of) shows that there are functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ which are continuous , surjective , takes every value at most a finite no. times but are not monotone ; this shows that $n$ exists finitely .

Comment: $2$, as the first (or second) answer in the linked question demonstrated.

Comment: @T.Bongers $2$ or $3$?

Comment: @M.Vinay As your answer showed, there is a continuous surjection that takes every value at most $3$ times and is not strictly monotone, so $n$ is not $3$.

Comment: @T.Bongers Weird, I read your comment as saying $3$. And I commented after around $7$ minutes, so you couldn't have edited it after that. I guess you edited just before I commented and I didn't see it.